# Smart Collection with Inclusive OR?

Tags: shopify

Can a Smart Collection be created in such a way that includes all products matching one of two tags?  In other words, the criteria would be  Tag=A *or* Tag=B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shopify provides the condition **product tag = something**. There is no boolean other than **AND** to connect them, therefore the answer seems quite clearly to be no.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve similar functionality there are a few apps on the store that can help, for example this: http://apps.shopify.com/power-tools-auto-collections, which allows you to create a collection that gives additional rules for OR and NOT.

Or you can even use this as a free option https://apps.shopify.com/power-tools-bulk-edit-tags, which allows you to add new tags so you can easily create a new collection

*disclaimer - I'm the developer of these apps